# Py requests, 'No connection adapters were found'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 644, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/manual.html"'
```

The url has https, and I've run a request from my terminal to this url with no issue so I'm lost as to why it can't find an adapter. I've looked into the source code and it's definitely there for https under default connection adapters

```
self.adapters = OrderedDict()
self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())
self.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter())
```

Thanks for any help

code:

```
def fetchUrl(self, url):
    response = requests.get(url, params=self.PAYLOAD)
```

and the payload

```
PAYLOAD = {
        'timeout': 60,
        'headers': {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have superfluous quotes in your `url` parameter.

Look closely at the URL string in your error message, it says (pay attention to the quotes)

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/manual.html"'
```

when instead it should say

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/manual.html'
```

Comment: Thanks, the url string was coming from a config file which I thought required var = "text" but instead is supposed to just be var = text